# Data in Rich Text Box Control does not submit - Browser Compatibility issue

Tags: infopath

I have a customized list in my SharePoint 2010 Website. I used Infopath 2010 to change the layout and add some specific controls. I added a rich text box control and a submit button.

When using Google Chrome, Safari or earlier versions of IE, the data is not submitted if I hit the submit button and the rich text box is highlighted. I can't submit the data unless I click on an other control before or I use the Save button in the ribbon.

If I use Firefox or IE8 or 9 the data in the rich text box is submitted without issues even when the the text box is highlighted and I hit my submit button directly.

Does the Rich Text Box Control have browser limitations? Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

Thank you,

Best,

Anas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with the Rich Text Box control.  On older versions of IE and on WebKit (Chrome/Safari), the JavaScript that saves the content for the Rich Text Control to the underlying control that SharePoint retrieves its data from on submit doesn't trigger until you select another control.

Comment: Thank you John for your response. Do you know of any hotfix by microsoft for this issue? or do I have to ask my users to use Firefox?

Comment: I am not aware of any hotfix.  Even though Chrome and Safari are now "officially" supported web browsers for SharePoint 2010, some stuff still doesn't perform optimally or as one would expect.  I doubt this will get resolved in 2010, but I could be wrong with a future update.

Comment: For Chrome users, you could encourage the use of the IE Tab extension.  That will render the page using IE, but wrap it in Chrome.

Comment: Here is the link for the IE Tab extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd

Comment: Thank you Jhon. This was very helpful, I really appreciate it.